Finding out which columns are same in different files
I have a data frames in R in the global environment :
file_1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
file_2 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, D = 16:20, E = 21:25)
file_3 <- data.frame(B = 6:10, C = 11:15, F = 26:30)

I want to make a matrix that helps me understand which column names are common in all data frames and which are not.
I tried to do this manually:
for (file in files) {
  data <- get(file)
  column_names[[file]] <- colnames(data)
}

all_columns <- unique(unlist(column_names))
matrix <- sapply(column_names, function(cols) all_columns %in% cols)
rownames(matrix) <- all_columns

matrix_df <- as.data.frame(matrix)

print(matrix_df)

Is this the correct way to do this in R?
BTW, if they were in a list, I think we could do it like this:
all_columns <- unique(unlist(lapply(mylist, colnames)))

matrix <- sapply(mylist, function(df) all_columns %in% colnames(df))
rownames(matrix) <- all_columns

matrix_df <- as.data.frame(matrix)

print(matrix_df)


Do you mean a matrix like below?
> table(stack(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "file_")), names)))
      ind
values file_1 file_2 file_3
     A      1      1      0
     B      1      0      1
     C      1      0      1
     D      0      1      0
     E      0      1      0
     F      0      0      1


shoot. Same answer. 19sec apart

@ThomasIsCoding: thank you so much!

Is it possible to write an extra line of code that creates a new file "file_4" that vertically stacks the other files, but only the common columns?

@farrow90 should you show a expected output for after adding "file_4"?

it would be like rbind(file_1, file_2, file_3) if this were possible ...

@farrow90 I cannot rbind them since they have different column names.

e.g. we identify the common columns in all files ... and then rbind these?

@farrow90 could you elaborate it in a new question?
